# Tableau bar chart with multiple level x-axis (or header)

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm new to Tableau and I'm trying to re-create the excel bar chart below (in Tableau; ignore the line and dual y-axis), but the problem is that Tableau doesn't seem to understand a multi-level x-axis (or header, as it calls it). All I'm getting is weird or very unsuitable chart displays! Is there even a way of splitting the x-axis in Tableau? Do I have to put the data in a specific table format first?

[image]

Here is the closest example of the data I'm dealing with (unfortunately I can't post the actual table). The data goes up to 31/03/22

[image]

I've browsed lost of documentation, but so far, all I found is related to Y-axis and not headers (as Tableau likes to call x-axis).

All help and suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tableau there is a feature called the dual axis. You need to apply that on the two measures in "Rows", that should be useful

[image]